# Sql result set to Csv with Java, cant parse because of semicolon characters in the text

Tags: java, mysql, sql, excel, csv

I'm trying to parse SQL result set into CSV and so far I was successful. But when I have tried to parse stuff like

```
<span style="color: rgb(0,0,0); font-family: 'Times New Roman'; </span> this, it sees that as a header column and puts that in there.
```

My expected result is:

```
Name; |Notes;|Version;|Status

Name1;|<span style="color: rgb(0,0,0); font-family: 'Times New Roman'; </span>;| 1;| Active |
```

But instead of that, I got this

```
Name;|Notes;|Version;|Status

Name1;|<span style="color: rgb(0,0,0);| font-family: 'Times New Roman';| </span>;| 1;| Active|
```

When I try this query at MySQL its table shows it nicely, but when I convert this to CSV file and open it in excel, it's catastrophic because of the semicolons in the Notes area. Any idea how to fix this?

**EDIT:**

My problem is with Excel, how it sees my data and parse it wrong due to one column contains semicolons, it separates that column into more. Is there a way for me to do something like storing it in quotes or anything?

**Expected Result:**
[image: Expected Result:]

**Problematic Result:**
[image: Problematic Result]

**EDIT 2:**

```
 public void writeWithOpenCsv (String filename, List<String[]> rows) throuws IO Exception{
     try (CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(filename))){
          writer.writeAll(rows);
         }
    }
```

Comment: show some code of what you've tried. Seems you need to escape the ; inside the returned values?

Comment: I need excel to see all the text in notes area ( which contains semicolons) as a context of one header. But it splits it to all other headers.

Comment: Again: Show us what you've tried so far. As you'll be opening with Excel anyway: Think about using Apache POI to directly create Excel spreadsheet instead

Comment: You should use a library like OpenCSV.

Comment: I am already using it :(

Comment: You should use a proper escape char and separator char with OpenCSV. Hard to say which you use, you haven't posted any code. But it is obviously wrong.

Comment: Kai i solved my problem you can read the answer, it had nothing to do with the code so for the next time i advice you to read the question more carefully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was not with the code, but with excel and the format of CSV.

I've learned that there are ways to solve this issue.
If your column content includes your parsing delimeter like ';' or ',' you could use quote (") signs to solve this issue.

**For example:**

> Name;Numbers //These are the headers
>
> Samed;14;3;2

when excel opens this its like

```
Name  | Numbers |     |
Samed |    14   |  3  |  2
```

So, like mysql most things cant import this because its out of range of headers.

When you quote, it doesnt see quote character and Samed;"14;3;2;" data will be seen like this:

> Name;Numbers
>
> Samed;"14;3;2"

```
Name  | Numbers   |   
Samed |  14;3;2   |
```

But if your data is a code and includes quote(") character (mine was) you can change your delimeter via typing

> sep=$
>
> Name$Numbers
>
> Samed$14";3;2

and it will give the result

```
Name  | Numbers   |   
Samed |  14";3;2  |
```

Keep in mind that in mysql import wizard it doesnt show anything like "$" to be used as delimeter.

For that you could use sql query:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:\test.csv'
INTO TABLE test.testColumns
TERMINATED BY '$'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

And it will work just fine